# C++ program to compute the number of strings w of length n over {a, b, c}

Tags: c++, permutation

I'm trying to generate all strings of length `n` such that any substring of length `4` of string `w`, all three letters `a, b, c` occur. For example, `abbcaabca` should be printed when `n = 9`, but `aabbcabac` should not be included.

Right now I'm only printing all the permutations, but I don't know how to only print the ones for this language.

```
void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
  char temp;
  temp = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{

  int i;
  if (l == r)
    printf("%s\n", a);

  else
    {
      for (i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
          swap((a+l), (a+i));
          permute(a, l+1, r);
          swap((a+l), (a+i));                                             
        }
    }
}

int main(){
  int n;
  cout << "Enter n: " << endl;
  cin >> n;
  char str[] = "abc";
  int x = n % 3;
  if (x != 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
      *str = *str + str[i];
  }
    permute(str, 0, n - 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: try to divide word into a characters . Then count it if count equal to n = 9 it should to print your letters

Comment: I tried to make it so that after n > 4 just to append characters to the calculated permutation of just length 4, but it just got really messy.

Comment: @Brittney Can you edit your question to include the relevant code please?

Comment: I would just generate the strings recursively. Given the set of strings of length k, for each string you can try all letters to form a k+1 length string. I think that's as far as anybody should help you with the algorithmic part. But if you get into problems with the coding, post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this solution ?

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void genStrList (std::set<std::string> & setStr,
                 std::size_t const       len,
                 std::string const     & nowStr,
                 std::string const     & poolCh)
 {
   int  i;

   std::set<char>  noLast3;

   std::string::const_reverse_iterator  cri;
   std::string::const_iterator          ci;

   if ( 2U < nowStr.size() )
    {
      for ( ci = poolCh.begin() ; ci != poolCh.end() ; ++ci )
         noLast3.insert(*ci);

      for ( cri = nowStr.rbegin(), i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++cri, ++i )
         noLast3.erase(*cri);
    }

   if ( 2U > noLast3.size() )
    {
      for ( ci = poolCh.begin() ; ci != poolCh.end() ; ++ci )
         if ( noLast3.empty() || (noLast3.end() != noLast3.find(*ci)) )
          {
            if ( nowStr.size() + 1U == len )
               setStr.insert(nowStr+(*ci));
            else
               genStrList(setStr, len, nowStr+(*ci), poolCh);
       }
    }
 }


int main()
 {
   std::size_t n;

   std::cout << "Enter n: " << std::endl;
   std::cin >> n;

   std::set<std::string>  setStr;

   genStrList(setStr, n, "", "abc");

   std::set<std::string>::const_iterator  ci;

   for ( ci = setStr.begin() ; ci != setStr.end() ; ++ci )
      std::cout << "- " << (*ci) << '\n';

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An obvious solution would be to augment the block

```
/* ... */
  if (l == r)
    printf("%s\n", a);
/* ... */
```

so that it checks whether the string `a` satisfies the condition, i.e., whether for each index `3 <= i < n` in the past four characters (`a[i-3], ..., a[i]`) each of the letters `a`, `b`, and `c` occurs. This is done easily in time `O(n)` (where `n` is the length of the string `a`). The overall running time increases from `O(n!)` to `O(n!*n)`.

A more "clever" solution would be to run a bookkeeping---a global variable that you modify in each recursive call---so that you can prune the bad branches early (i.e. you don't make further recursive calls if the beginning of the string violates the condition). The running time in this case would be `o(n!)` (i.e. asymptotically faster than `n!`; see [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)).